# Click Button on Web Page programmatically/Get Element Tag Name using Android Browser

Tags: android, browser, tags

Let me start by saying StackOverflow has been a great tool for me as I learn Android development.

What I am trying to figure out is how to click on the ‘OK’ button when I am using the default Android web browser and the following message appears: (Sorry, I can’t post pics yet)

“You are using an unsupported version of Mozilla.

Please upgrade your browser to the latest version before logging in.”

I can’t use Chrome Debug because the “unsupported version” message doesn’t appear when I use the new version of Chrome. I don’t want the users of my app to have to download Chrome to be able to use my app.
I know I can use “document.getElementsByTagName('OK Button Element Tag Name').click();” but how would I find the Element Tag Name without the use of Chrome Debug?

Thanks in advance,
Ken

Comment: Picture of "unsupported version" message: http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/2194/screenshotff.png

Comment: Note: If I open url in a webview I don't get this message however, if I want to show the progress while the page is loading using webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() the message pops up.